# Bags-list pallet test case not running

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, rust

I am using the polkadot version 0.9.36, I run test cases of all the pallets in the frame by using the **cargo test** command, every pallet test case is working fine but when I run the bags-list pallet test case it shows some error like this

```rs
T::ScoreProvider::set_score_of(&origin_middle, dest_bag_thresh);  
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `<T as pallet::Config<I>>::ScoreProvider`
```

Comment: Could you try with the latest code?

Comment: latest code it works. I confirm 36 doesn't run - probably needs anothe PR to be cherry picked into the branch if people still want it fixed.